# Calendar appearing again after changing tabs or minimizing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) jquery plugin and applying it to a field in a form page.

When the user clicks on the input field, there are 2 possible options I'm dealing with:

1. the calendar appears and the user selects a date (after that the calender automatically closes)
2. the user just close the calendar (selecting no dates)

What's happening is that after one of the 2 options above, if the user opens another tab in the browser (and then go back to the form tab) or minimize the browser (and then open it again in form tab), the calender shows up again.

This only happens if the last field selected is the one with the pickadate plugin applied to. If the user selects another field that does not contain the pickadate plugin and does that same process (of changing tabs or minimizing browser), the calender doesn't appear again.

What should I do to does not make the calender appear if the last field select is the one with the pickadate plugin applied to?

The code that calls the plugin is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate();
});
```

Comment: Did you contact the developer? :)

Comment: of course it's probably the way it was made but I'm assuming there is a way to avoid that

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1** (This method worked for me)

Add onOpen to the initialization object.

```
var $input = $('.datepicker');
$input.pickadate({
    onOpen: function () {
        if ($input.hasClass('picker__input--target')) {
            $input.pickadate().pickadate('picker').close(true);
        }
    }
});
```

**Method 2** (This method didn't work for me. Maybe I didn't code it right).

Add onClose to the initialization object.

```
var $input = $('.datepicker');
$input.pickadate({
    onClose: function() {
            $input.blur();
        }
    }
});
```

[Source from github](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/160)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that when the tab with the picker is brought back to focus the focus event for that input is being called again, thus causing the picker to pop back up.

I would tie into the window focus event

```
window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    // make sure input in question is not in focus
});
```

then make sure input in question is not in focus